# Cannot resolve overloaded method thenReturn

Tags: scala, file, testing, mockito, scalatest

I'm new to Scala. I'm working on the following code where one API endpoint is caching value in the file(SomeJsonData.toString()) and the other endpoint is retrieving from that file(Json.parse()). When writing a test using when-thenReturn, getting an overloaded method error.

Where am I going wrong?

Cache File contents:

```
{"time":92345845,"value":[{"name":"Jack","hobby":"paint"}]
```

CacheController.scala

```
def retrieveCache = {
    File(filePath).createFile()
    val source = Source.fromFile(filePath)
    val content = try source.mkString
    .....       
}
```

CacheControllerTest.scala

```
it("test") {
    val mockSuggestions = "[{\"name\":\"Jack\",\"hobby\":\"paint\"}]"
    val jsonData =Json.obj("time" -> DateTime.now(), "value" -> mockSuggestions)

    when(Source.fromFile(anyString())).thenReturn(jsonData.toString())
    // error: cannot resolve overloaded method thenReturn
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Source.fromFile` returns a `BufferedSource`, so you'd have to pass it one of those in `thenReturn` instead of a String.